# Mangling of French unicode when webscraping with rvest

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, utf-8, rvest

I'm looking at scraping a French website using the rvest package.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.vins-bourgogne.fr/nos-vins-nos-terroirs/tous-les-bourgognes/toutes-les-appellations-de-bourgogne-a-votre-portee,2378,9172.html?&args=Y29tcF9pZD0xMzg2JmFjdGlvbj12aWV3RnVsbExpc3RlJmlkPSZ8"
s <- read_html(url)
s %>% html_nodes('#resultatListeAppellation .lien') %>% html_text()
```

I expect to see:

```
Aloxe-Corton (Appellation Village, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÔTE DE BEAUNE)
Auxey-Duresses (Appellation Village, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÔTE DE BEAUNE)
Bâtard-Montrachet (Appellation Grand Cru, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÔTE DE BEAUNE)
```

Instead, I see the diacritic characters mangled (see line 3 below):

```
"Aloxe-Corton (Appellation Village, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÃ\u0094TE DE BEAUNE)"        
"Auxey-Duresses (Appellation Village, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÃ\u0094TE DE BEAUNE)"      
"BÃ¢tard-Montrachet (Appellation Grand Cru, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÃ\u0094TE DE BEAUNE)"
```

The source html of the page shows it's encoded in utf-8. Using guess_encoding() on the html_text(), it suggests utf-8 as well (1.00 confidence), or windows-1252 with 0.73 confidence. Changing the encoding to windows-1252 doesn't help matters:

```
"Aloxe-Corton (Appellation Village, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÃ”TE DE BEAUNE)"                                                                                
"Auxey-Duresses (Appellation Village, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÃ”TE DE BEAUNE)"                                                                              
"BÃ¢tard-Montrachet (Appellation Grand Cru, VIGNOBLE DE LA CÃ”TE DE BEAUNE)"
```

I tried the same code on a different French website (also encoded utf-8):

```
x <- read_html('http://www.lemonde.fr/disparitions/article/2017/12/06/johnny-hallyday-c-etait-notre-seule-rock-star-la-france-perd-son-icone-du-rock_5225507_3382.html')
x %>% html_nodes('.taille_courante+ p , .croix_blanche , .tt2') %>% html_text()
```

Now I get the diacritics etc:

```
[1] "Johnny Hallyday : « C’était notre seule rock star », « La France perd son icône du rock »"                                                                                                                                                                                           
[2] "« Comme toute la France, mon cœur est brisé, a déclaré à l’Agence France-Presse (AFP) la chanteuse Sylvie Vartan, qui fut la première épouse de Johnny Hallyday, et mère de leur fils, David, né en 1966. J’ai perdu l’amour de ma jeunesse et rien ne pourra jamais le remplacer. »"
```

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong with the first website? Or how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird website. It is not all valid UTF-8:

```
lines <- readLines(url, warn = FALSE)
all(utf8::utf8_valid(lines))
#> [1] FALSE
```

Here are the offending lines:

```
lines[!utf8::utf8_valid(lines)]
#> [1] "// on supprime l'\xe9ventuel cookie"                                                                             
#> [2] "//Ouverture et fermeture de l'encart r\xe9saux sociaux lors d'un clic sur le bouton"                             
#> [3] "//Cr\xe9ation de l'iframe facebook \xe0 la premi\xe8re ouverture de l'encart pour qu'elle fasse la bonne largeur"
#> [4] "//fermeture de l'encart r\xe9saux sociaux lors d'un clic ailleurs sur la page"
```

These look like comments in the JavaScript code. I suspect that `read_html` realizes that the page is not all valid UTF-8 and interprets the encoding to be Windows-1252 or some other 8-bit coding scheme.

You could try to work around this by removing the offending JS segments:

```
content <- paste(lines[utf8::utf8_valid(lines)], collapse = "\n")
content %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('#resultatListeAppellation .lien') %>% html_text()
```

This gives the expected output.