# R encoding problem while web scraping - how to fix broken text?

Tags: r, web-scraping, encoding, character-encoding

While web scraping, some of the text retrieved was broken, very similar with foreign text when the incorrect encoding is used. The problem is: the encoding seems to be correct: "UTF-8".
Is there any way to fix the text, even though it is supposedly in the correct format? The chunk  of code below is the problem reported here.
Rstudio is configured with "UTF-8" encoding, and functions that changes the encoding used always returns even more gibberish. 
Thank you all in advance.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2020/01/folhas-da-manha-da-tarde-e-da-noite-se-uniram-sob-um-so-titulo-folha-de-spaulo-ha-60-anos.shtml"

title.news <- html_text(read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes('body') %>%
    html_nodes('main') %>%
    html_nodes('article') %>%
    html_nodes('.block') %>%
    html_nodes('h1'))

title.news <- trimws(gsub(pattern = '\\s+', ' ', title.news))

Encoding(title.news)
[1] "UTF-8"

title.news
[1] "Folhas da ManhÃ£, da Tarde e da Noite se uniram sob um sÃ³ tÃ­tulo, Folha de S.Paulo, hÃ¡ 60 anos"

#Desired Output: Folhas da Manhã, da Tarde e da Noite se uniram sob um só título, Folha de S.Paulo, há 60 anos
```

Comment: This is a tough one. The website source is utf-8 and rvest detects it as utf-8 so I don't see where it gets mangled

Comment: This looks like an `rvest` bug:  If you look at the source in a browser, it appears to be encoded consistently in UTF-8, but even running `html_text(read_html(url))` displays a mix of correctly encoded text and messed up text.  I'd expect this on Windows (where I'd blame R), but I'm on MacOS, with UTF-8 as my native encoding.

Comment: Does https://www.tfzx.net/article/4731720.html help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677540/mangling-of-french-unicode-when-webscraping-with-rvest) but I honestly don't know why it works.

To start with there are some misencoded lines which you can check with `utf8::utf8_valid`

```
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

url <- "https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2020/01/folhas-da-manha-da-tarde-e-da-noite-se-uniram-sob-um-so-titulo-folha-de-spaulo-ha-60-anos.shtml"
lines <- readLines(url, warn = FALSE)
lines[!utf8::utf8_valid(lines)]
#> [1] "  Esse trecho est\xe1 em produ\xe7\xe3o para dar suporte aos componentes de chamadas,"
#> [2] "  p\xe1ginas serem republicadas."                                                     
#> [3] "  Trecho de c\xf3digo adicionado para renomear legenda abaixo das publicdades,"
```

Which are comments in the page source html. Stripping them out makes the functions work as expected

```
lines <- readLines(url, warn = FALSE)
content <- paste(lines[utf8::utf8_valid(lines)], collapse = "\n")
content %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('body') %>%
    html_nodes('main') %>%
    html_nodes('article') %>%
    html_nodes('.block') %>%
    html_nodes('h1') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    {trimws(gsub(pattern = '\\s+', ' ', .))}
#> [1] "Folhas da Manhã, da Tarde e da Noite se uniram sob um só título, Folha de S.Paulo, há 60 anos"
```

Created on 2020-01-13 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

Comment: Just tried this solution and, for some reason, it didn't work. The results obtained are null and the same broken text in the end. As if there was nothing wrong with the site. In fact, `all(utf8::utf8_valid(lines))` returns true. Is there any reason for such strange discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help! The following chunk solved the problem

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)

url <- "https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2020/01/folhas-da-manha-da-tarde-e-da-noite-se-uniram-sob-um-so-titulo-folha-de-spaulo-ha-60-anos.shtml"

pagina.web <- iconv(readLines(url, encoding = 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8', sub = '')

titulo.noticia <- read_html(paste0(pagina.web, collapse = '\n')) %>%
  html_nodes('body') %>%
  html_nodes('main') %>%
  html_nodes('article') %>%
  html_nodes('.block') %>%
  html_nodes('h1') %>%
  html_text()

titulo.noticia
```

Comment: Reading the file line by line and then pasting them is a bit excentric. The call to iconv to convert from 'UTF-8' to 'UTF-8' seems to me uterly wrong. As I tried that, it removed the characters with diacritic from the string. I posted my attempt as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer of GBLucass:

```
library(rvest)
library(readr)

html.src <- read_file(url, locale = locale(encoding="UTF-8"))
html.parse <- read_html(url)
```

This reads the page to a string first with correct encoding and parses it from the string. It seems to circumvent the problem.